# Perl ack tool with output parameter and new lines

Tags: ack

I use `ack` very often, but something I have not been able to discover is how to make it add new lines when using the output parameter.

Example

```
echo 'name=Joe,id=123' | ack '^name=(\w+),id=(\d+)' --output="User name: $1\nUser ID: $2"
```

I expect

```
User name: Joe
User ID: 123
```

but I get

```
User name: Joe\nUser ID: 123
```

Anyway to make `ack` respect the new lines characters in the output?

Thanks

Comment: Has nothing to do with `ack`. Pass a newline instead of `\n`. What shell are you asking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `\n` to `ack` instead of a newline. Replace

```
--output='User name: $1\nUser ID: $2'
```

with

```
--output='User name: $1
User ID: $2'
```

or

```
--output="$( printf 'User name: $1\nUser ID: $2' )"
```

or

```
--output=$'User name: $1\nUser ID: $2'                   # bash
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put arbitrary code into that string via `@{[ … ]}` interpolation. For some reason a literal `"\n"` string won't work, but `chr 0x0A` or `$/` does.

Example:

```
$ echo a b | ack '(\w+)\s+(\w+)' --output '$1@{[ chr 0x0A ]}$2'
```

Output:

```
a
b
```

Note that this kind of functionality is likely to break in the future, see also discussions like https://github.com/beyondgrep/ack2/issues/531

Comment: Author of ack here.  `@{[ … ]}` is absolutely not going to work in ack 3, currently under development. It's too dangerous.  We've severely limited what can be done with `--output`.